# Django 2 migrate is not creating table in MySql?

Tags: mysql, django, migration

I am using django and mysql. When i do migrate after making some models at first time then it creates all the table in the database properly but after that migrate succeed when i do some changes or  create new models then it doesn't creates the new table in the database even it says the migrate successful.I always do `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` after some changes in model .I deleted all the `migrations` and run `python manage.py makemigrations` it displays all the model i have created in the `models.py` but after `migrate` it doesnot creates the new table. I even tried `python manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME` and `python manage.py migrate`  after `makemigrations` but nothing happened in the database.***But when i delete the whole database*** and create the new one then it creates the all the tables but i am not interested to delete whole database after some changes or creating new models everytime

> settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
        'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
    },
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try the command by adding `appname` after `makemigrations`?

Comment: Did you add the app in installed apps list before running migrate? because it works all the time for me. I have done this multiple times, also you need to provide the models and settings both to figure out what exactly the problem is

Comment: @AmartyaGaur i have the app name in the installed apps list .When i delete the whole database and re-create it then it creates the table

Comment: @ans2human i tried by by adding `python manage.py migrate appname` after `makemigrations` also

Comment: could you also post output screenshots along with what you're doing because there seems no error in your approach as of now and it should theoretically work and @ans2human was talking about command : python manage.py makemigrations appname

Comment: Please post the stack trace errors.